# Access to AWS Opensearch in a VPC using IAM Role (ec2 instance profile)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-opensearch

I have an OpenSearch domain set up within a VPC, and there is an EC2 instance running in the same VPC. The EC2 instance has an IAM role attached to its instance profile, granting full permissions to access the OpenSearch domain. However, when attempting to read or write to the domain from the EC2 instance, a 401 Unauthorized error is encountered.

For example

I can do whatever I wish with OpenSearch domain using aws cli on this ec2. for example

`aws opensearch upgrade-domain --domain-name opensearch-blui --target-version OpenSearch_2.5` works but when I try to create an index in the cluster, it fails.
`curl -XPUT https://opensearch.lol.net/movies/_doc/1 -d '{"director": "Burton, Tim", "genre": ["Comedy","Sci-Fi"], "year": 1996, "actor": ["Jack Nicholson","Pierce Brosnan","Sarah Jessica Parker"], "title": "Mars Attacks!"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

`Unauthorized`

Is it not possible to use IAM to authenticate with Opensearch to make actual use of it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have edited the question to include commands.
Do you mean when using OpenSearch within a VPC, IAM authentication is insufficient for request authentication and authorization. IAM primarily serves AWS service operations. To read/write in OpenSearch, I must use OpenSearch-specific authentication mechanisms like basic auth or OpenSearch Security (Open Distro for Elasticsearch) with users and roles.
Pls correct my understanding or point me to the relevent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Check the IAM policy associated with the IAM role. It should have the correct permissions for OpenSearch. Here is an example:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:domain/DOMAIN_NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Verify that your VPC Security Group allows inbound and outbound access between your EC2 instance and your OpenSearch domain.
- The OpenSearch domain's access policy should be configured to permit access from the IAM role attached to your EC2 instance.
- Confirm that your EC2 instance is indeed associated with the IAM role.
  Note: It can sometimes take a few minutes for the new permissions to propagate throughout AWS.
- When making requests to the OpenSearch domain, ensure that you're using AWS Signature Version 4 signing process. AWS OpenSearch Service requires all incoming requests to be signed using Signature Version 4

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and couldn't find any sort of documentation on how to manage IAM access using roles and users, but found an effective, quick workaround.

Simply edit your domain security configuration and under `Amazon OpenSearch Service > Domains > your-domain-name > Edit security configuration / Fine-grained access control`, select `Set IAM ARN as master user` and provide your instance role arn and save the change.

[image: Edit security configuration]

Once your settings have saved, if you are using a non-IAM ARN master user, go back into the same settings panel, selecting `Create master user` and restore the credentials for your master user and save.

Note that this works because these IAM master user changes are purely additive as laid out in the fine print:

> "Creating a new master user does not delete the existing master user"

***Importantly, note that setting an IAM ARN as master user, however, does remove the non-IAM ARN master user you had previously, if any, so you will indeed need to restore said user/credentials as stated above.***

Also note that within the OpenSearch dashboard itself you will see various indications of some sort of mapping between iam roles/users and index permissions but with no readily accessible documentation around how to navigate that (although I find it surprising and would expect this to be a primary use case) and given that this works without getting deep into the weeds beyond the AWS side of things, for now I have ended my own search for something that feels like the "right solution."